# IE11 Edge browsers div border-radius isn't smooth

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When you scale a div element close to the rounded corner it appears that in IE11 and Edge the corners aren't smooth. I checked in Chrome 49 and latest FF and it works fine.

Please see [the demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsckV.png). You should have access to code in the demo.

[image]

My question is: do you know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: you need to share code

Comment: Here is a link to his demo : http://codepen.io/DamianS1987/pen/YqEraz

Comment: Please don't circumvent the quality filter.

Comment: You are using scale, not border radius. Maybe Edge has got the same antialiasing than the typography (the microsoft crap called TrueType, that's not True nor Type).

Comment: I asked around, and the best answer I got was that it could be due to rounding happening with the way it draws it with hardware acceleration. Also, testing shows that the glitch only happens at some scale sizes. Perhaps you could investigate that further to see if you could set your code to scale only to sizes that render correctly. My other thought was that depending on what you're trying to achieve with this, you might find that an SVG graphic is more appropriate anyway; that might be a work-around for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers, I'm working on an app that uses zoom functionality to highlight some elements details. Unfortunately, the element has to be a div due to backend server requirements.
Btw, I have reported the issue to Edge - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7114904/